# shopify 422 Unprocessable Entity exception utf-8 characters

Tags: rest, http, kotlin, shopify

I am passing some chinese character in shopify new product PUT request with below utf-8 string.

```
"%E7%94%A8%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C"
```

I am passing content-type as "application/json;charset=UTF-8". But shopify throws 422 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Id was missing in the metafields payload. Shopify response could have pointed out exactly what is problem! Wasted my one hour!

Comment: A product has many attributes. Any one of which could be missing, screwed up or otherwise malformed. For Shopify to cherry pick which one and tell you, I guess they figure that is just too much. They just lump your whole payload in as no good. 

In this case, you have to know a PUT requires a resource ID, so you probably should not have wasted an hour trying to figure that out, that is the basics. It is not like Rest is a new idea these days.